# Image not showing in listview in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, imagelist

I am working on Winforms where I am saving path of image in database, and then retrieving the path and giving it to Imagelist. The images from Image list are used in ImageView. But the image is not displaying, its path is correctly displayed but image is not showing.

```
public void yourvideos(string user, ImageList imageList, ListView lv, Label l,TextBox s)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select Title,Thumbnail from RecipeInfo where Username=@username", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                int count = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    s.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                    imageList.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);
                    imageList.Images.Add("key"+count,Image.FromFile($@"{reader[1]}"));
                   
                    var listviewitem = lv.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString(), count);
                    
                    listviewitem.ImageKey = "key" + count;
                  count++;
                }
                

                
            }
            else
            {

                l.Visible = true;
                l.Text = "Upload videos and share your recipes with others";
            }
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: `count++` i used so that every new image has change imagekey

Comment: If the query returns just one User, then you'll have no Images (wrong key). If it returns more than one user, wrong image for all except the first (no image). Use just `lv.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString(), count);` and increment the counter after. Time to learn how to debug your code.

Comment: at first count is 0 and then first image that is storing in imagelist has value key0 and then count increment and it value become 1 and new list will have value key1

Comment: I correct the code by placing count++ at the end

Comment: user is foreign key and one user has multiple images

Comment: @Jimi I did what u mentioned but nothing happened

Comment: Did you set the ImageList as the `ListView.SmalImageList` or `ListView.LargeImageList` or whatever? What is the `ListView.View` property set to? etc. If you did what I suggested, then your code has changed, you need to update your question and add the (required) Controls specifics.

Comment: BTW, you can have simply `imageList.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(reader[1].ToString()));`. Then use the counter as the `int` indexer for the Images: `lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(reader[0].ToString(), count)); count++;`.

Comment: I tried but nothing is working out, even if I don't give path from database and give directly at that time, still no image is showing. This is function in class which I am calling in Form.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurred when I used the `key`, and I solved it with the `Index`.
You can refer to my code：

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                
        this.listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
       yourvideos(this.imageList1,this.listView1);
    }
    public void yourvideos( ImageList imageList1, ListView listView1)
    {
        string sql = "...";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sql);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Title,Thumbnail from RecipeInfo", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int i = 0;
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string title = reader["Title"].ToString();
                string picurl = reader["Thumbnail"].ToString();
                imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(60, 60);
                imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(picurl));
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.Text = Convert.ToString(title);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
                item.ImageIndex = i;
                i++;

            }
        }
        listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();

    }
```

Result:

[image]